# PySpark - change dataframe column value based on its existence in other dataframe

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I am relatively new in using Spark and didn't find out solution for this. I found several similar questions related to this but didn't find the way how to bundle this in my use-case.

I have two dataframes, first is based on CSV which looks like this (displayed as table):

| id | license_no |
| --- | --- |
| 2005 | 1011 |
| 2006 | 1022 |
| 2007 | 3911 |

Second dataframe is based on CSV which looks like this:

| license_no | active |
| --- | --- |
| 1011 | y |
| 1022 | y |
| 3911 | n |

I need to check does license_no value exists in second dataframe, and if it exists and active=y, then I need to add some prefix (99 in the beginning) to its id and license_no in first dataframe - for example, license_id exists in second dataframe and it is active, so its ID in first dataframe should be changed to 992005 and license_no do 991011. If doesn't exits 88 should be added.

Dataframe should look like this after transformations:

| id | license_no |
| --- | --- |
| 992005 | 991011 |
| 992006 | 991022 |
| 882007 | 883911 |

I am not sure what is best solution for this, can I directly do this transformation in one spark command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#Join

```
s = df.join(df1,how='left',on='license_no')
```

#Contitionally concat prefix using list squares

```
s.select(*[when(col('active')=='y',concat(lit('99'),str(x))).otherwise(concat(lit('88'),str(x))).alias(x) for x in s.columns if x!='active']).show()


+----------+------+
|license_no|    id|
+----------+------+
|    991011|992005|
|    991022|992006|
|    883911|882007|
```

+----------+------+

Comment: Reference 'license_no' is ambiguous, could be: license_no, license_no. But you gave me idea how to proceed with this. Thank you!

Comment: You can try the following if you are ending up with an ambigous column `s = df.join(df1.alias('df1'),how='left',on=df.license_no==df1.license_no).drop(df1.license_no)`